# Почему в причине закрытия нет пункта "здесь не бесплатный freelance"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

На Русском СО появляется множество вопросов на тему "напишите мне код", некоторые даже как выдержка из т.з. собственно сам вопрос: Почему в причине закрытия нет пункта "здесь не бесплатный freelance"?

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @Nofate тут вопрос не о задачах с каким то кодом и т.д. А о реально технических заданиях, мне нужен сайт что бы была регистрация, админка и т.д. Хотя в какой то мере вы правы.

Comment: @Naumov "слишком обширен" же.